# meta-qt5 yocto layer does not compile

Tags: qt, qt5, yocto, bitbake

I compile the image and SDK for board using Yocto. Compiling the image(without `-c populate_sdk`) looks ok, but when I try to populate an SDK I get a couple of errors (seems the issue is in "meta-qt5" layer).

So, I use `bitbake <image_name> -c populate_sdk`. The branch is `rocko`. After executing bitbake i get the next errors:

```
ERROR: qt3d-5.9.8+gitAUTOINC+0d923f9fc3-r0 do_compile: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/IMX6/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-phytec-linux-gnueabi/qt3d/5.9.8+gitAUTOINC+0d923f9fc3-r0/temp/log.do_compile.2150)
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/IMX6/build/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-phytec-linux-gnueabi/qt3d/5.9.8+gitAUTOINC+0d923f9fc3-r0/temp/log.do_compile.2150
ERROR: Task (/opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/IMX6/sources/poky/../meta-qt5/recipes-qt/qt5/qtwebkit_git.bb:do_compile) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 5415 tasks of which 5406 didn't need to be rerun and 2 failed.
NOTE: Writing buildhistory

Summary: 2 tasks failed:
  /opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/IMX6/sources/poky/../meta-qt5/recipes-qt/qt5/qt3d_git.bb:do_compile
  /opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/IMX6/sources/poky/../meta-qt5/recipes-qt/qt5/qtwebkit_git.bb:do_compile
```

Here are the log files: [qt_webkit](https://pastebin.com/zRfwfyz3) and [qt3d](https://pastebin.com/1R2VafkJ). They are quite large but can be useful.

Also, I compile it on Ubuntu 16.04 Virtual machine (4 CPU, 8GB RAM)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution for Ubuntu 18.04.

For building SDK It's necessary to install some additional software.
Try to exec the next commands and re-run the bitbake.

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y -q --no-install-recommends -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef" \
-o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" build-essential chrpath cpio diffstat file  \
g++-multilib gawk gcc-multilib git-core locales openssh-client python python3 \
socat sudo texinfo tmux unzip wget

sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

sudo locale-gen en_US.UTF-8

export LANG='en_US.UTF-8' LANGUAGE='en_US:en' LC_ALL='en_US.UTF-8'
```

I am not sure about Ubuntu 16.04, but on 18.04 everything works fine for me.